# Passing query string from one page to another

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to pass a query string from one page to another page where AJAX will pick it up as the `url` and then get a return.

The method I'm using for the AJAX query string is to alter hidden form values with a separate  user interface form and then `.serialize` the hidden form values into a query string which AJAX gets and then runs it.

The initial "search" page would be on the home page and then the arguments would be passed tothe results page, but I don't know how to get them there.

With PHP, it would have been as simple as a POST form to the necessary page.  But I'm clueless as how to do it with AJAX.

Comment: you havent specified, but im assuming youre using jquery right? This might be too obvious but http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ is worth a look and maybe pop some code into http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can see where youre up to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the `data` argument of any jQuery AJAX function, eg. [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: That looks like it's getting the data from another page.  I want to push the variables gathered from the user at the first page into the AJAX call on the second page.

Comment: @Plummer So, do I understand correctly that you gather data on `page_A` and on `page_B` you want to use it? If yes, then how do you reach `page_B`?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm wanting to do.  I've been told a cookie is a way to accomplish this but have never used cookies before.

Comment: @Plummer See above: ***If yes, then how do you reach `page_B`?***